# What is the difference between the following while using Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

What is the difference between the following while using Tortoise SVN

1. SVN Checkout (in context menu)
2. Export (in context menu)
3. Save as (in Repo Browser)
4. Copy to.. (in Repo Browser)
5. Copy to working copy.. (in Repo Browser)

Answer (score 13):

1. SVN Checkout - Copy the files to a local folder and link them to the repository
2. Export - Same as 1, but not linked to the repository and with no extra control files laying around (can come from a working copy or the repository)
3. Save As - Export a single file, perhaps renaming it in the process
4. Copy to - Branch the file or folder into a location in the repository browser tree with an immediate commit.
5. Copy to working copy - Branch the file or folder into a working copy already on your machine with delayed commit.
   5a.Both 4 and 5 preserve SVN history. They differ in the ability to edit the results before committing.

Answer (score 0):

SVN Checkout will connect to your SVN repository and fetch a working copy. In a working copy, you can make changes to the files and when you do SVN Commit, the changes will be sent to the SVN repository. And SVN Update will update your working copy with the changes committed by other devlopers.

SVN Export can either connect to the repo or export a working copy on your local computer. Once you export a folder, you can no longer track changes made to it. (This will simply remove the hidden .svn folders).